# Recoding a subset of an existing data frame

Tags: r

Suppose:

```
x <- rep(1:6, 26)
y <- rep(letters, 6)
df.test <- data.frame(x,y)
```

What I would like to do is recode all of the column y == "a", x's as 1=6,2=5,3=4,4=3,5=2,6=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply by indexing?

```
x <- rep(1:6, 26)
y <- rep(letters, 6)
df.test <- data.frame(x,y)

df.test$x[df.test$y=="a"]=7-df.test$x[df.test$y=="a"]
```

Comment: Indexing is still one of my "gotcha's". I tried similar combinations of what you have here, but this one works (with the exception that I generally use <- rather than = for assignment). THanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
df.test$x[df.test$y == "a"] <- 7 - df.test$x[df.test$y == "a"]
```